# Why the Vanguard S&P 500 eur has such a lower price compared to the original US version?

Tags: investing, etf, currency, european-union, vanguard

sorry if this is a silly question but I am new to the finance world. I would like to understand better why the Vanguard S&P 500 UCITS ETF (VUSA) has such a different price compared to the Vanguard S&P 500 ETF (VOO:US). At the moment 47 euro vs 257 usd.

I know that the VOO has a much larger total asset size, but how would that impact my investment?

I am also aware that there is a currency exchange risk which plays a role in the different returns, but if I have EUR should I consider to invest in the original USD product?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand those 2 are separate funds that just happen to track the same equity. Both the total shares available for both as well as total AUM(assets under management) are different.

Keeping that in mind you can see why shares of each have different pricing as they represent different notional ownership of the net asset value (NAV) of each ETF.

If currency volatility isn't a factor to your choice choose whichever has the lowest expense ratio.

p.s. hedging against currency risks does incur costs so its natural such a product to carry higher expense rates.